# Trying to convert a string into a double

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a string into a double, but I have been unsuccessful up until now.
The string I got from the textbox is : "1^2" and I am trying to calculate it in the VB Editor.
I have tried the following syntax unsuccessfully :
*CDbl("1^2").

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `Application.Evaluate`.

Comment: The string conversion can be executed if the string is interpreted as numeric. "1^2" isn't regarded as a numeric string. - Furthermore converting a string to double uses regional settings (~> decimal separator) which could be of some interest in middle European countries if you try to exectue `CDbl("1.2")` instead of `CDbl("1,2").

Comment: @BigBen Thank you so much. It works fine.